# Hackerrank Python Challenge: Capitalize The First letter of each word in a String in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rank, capitalize

### Capitalize!

You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin with a capital letter in their passports. For example, alison heck should be capitalized correctly as Alison Heck.

Given a full name, your task is to capitalize the name appropriately.

**Input Format**

A single line of input containing the full name,

**Constraints**

- 0 < len(S) < 1000
- The string consists of alphanumeric characters and spaces.

**Note:** in a word only the first character is capitalized. Example 12abc when capitalized remains 12abc.

**Output Format**

Print the capitalized string,

**Sample Input**

*chris alan*

**Sample Output**

*Chris Alan*

Answer (score -2):

### SOLVED

```
s = '132 456 Wq  m ethiopia'
s_lists = s.split(' ')
name = ''
for s_list in s_lists:
    if len(s_list) > 0:
        if s_list[0].isdigit():
            name = name + s_list + ' '
        else:
            name = name + s_list[0].upper() + s_list[1:] + ' '
    else:
        name = name + ' '

print(name[:-1])
```

**Hackerrank Test cases**

[image]

> **Result**
>
> > 132 456 Wq  M Ethiopia

Comment: SO is not supposed to be a place to post arbitrary code puzzles and solutions.

Comment: `str.title` will lowercase every subsequent character after the first letter. So this might not work as a general solution

Comment: Give me one test case that will not work.

Comment: Why split the string and go through each part? print('132 456 Wq  m ethiopia'.title()) gives the same result except that it retains the double space in the original string.

Comment: Not working for input: "adam mcSomewhat" because the s will be lowercased.

Comment: What about now?